# Modifying XML using ElementTree in Python 2.6.6 - issue with namespace

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.5/jdbc-data-source.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls">
  <name>wlng.datasource</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://hwdbhost:3306/gwdb</url>
    ............
```

I am trying to update the text value of **url** tag and my code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filename = "wlng-mysql-single-jdbc.xml"

ET._namespace_map["http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source"] = ''
ET._namespace_map["http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security"] = "sec"
ET._namespace_map["http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"] = "xsi"
ET._namespace_map["http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls"] = "wls"

# Parse the file
tree = ET.parse(filename)
# Get the root element - Configuration
root = tree.getroot()
jdbcRoot = root.find('jdbc-driver-params')
for child in root:
    print child.tag
    #print child.tag.split("}")[1][0:]
    if child.tag.split("}")[1][0:] == "jdbc-driver-params":
        #print child.tag[0].tag
        for subchild in child:
            print subchild.tag.split("}")[1][0:]
            if subchild.tag.split("}")[1][0:] == "url":
                subchild.text = "newvalue1"

# Modifying the XML element with the new content
tree.write('test.xml',encoding="UTF-8")
```

After updating, there are 2 problems:

1) Even though I have registered all the namespaces, it ignores couple of namespaces. How do I preserve all namespaces as original?

2) All the elements are prefixed with a colon now. Like <:name>wlng.datasource. How can I avoid that.

The result XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<:jdbc-data-source xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.5/jdbc-data-source.xsd" xmlns:="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <:name>wlng.datasource</:name>
  <:jdbc-driver-params>
    <:url>newvalue1</:url>
    ............
```

Can someone please help me on this. The Python version is 2.6.6.

Regards,
Subeesh

Comment: This is weird, I've ran your code and got the desired results...

Comment: Oh, are you in python 2.6 ?

Comment: No, I'm on Python 2.7

Comment: Ok. I am executing this in 2.6. What could be the issue? What change i may need to do to make it work in 2.6 ?